# Javafx ScrollPane listen to keyboard event (key pressed)

Tags: javafx, keyboard-events, onkeypress, scrollpane, eventhandler

I've a ScrollPane and I want when I press the CTRL key an event in the scroll pane will be fired, here is my code that doesn't work ( when I press ctrl key nothing happened it doesnt even break on it )
this code i put it in the initialze(URL url, ResourceBundle rb)

```
@FXML private ScrollPane m_scrollPane;

m_scrollPane.setOnKeyPressed(new EventHandler<KeyEvent>() {

        public void handle(KeyEvent ke) {

            String text = ke.getCharacter();

                if (ke.isControlDown()) {
                //do something
                    text += " , ctrl down";
                }
            }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Is your initial(**I**)ze(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) called at all? Controller must implement Initializable in order to get it called.

If you are using JavaFX 2 or higher, the proper method is to use instead annotated initialize() without arguments (interface not needed then)

```
@FXML
void initialize() {
}
```

[... FXMLLoader will now automatically call any suitably annotated no-arg initialize() method...](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/fxml/Initializable.html)

If still doesn't work, ensure the pane has input focus.

By the way,  ke.getCharacter() in this event type will return empty string. 
key.getText() will return the pressed character, but note this event type is fired on any key, including Ctrl itself. Probably you would like to use setOnKeyTyped instead, where getCharacter() works.